# Caliburn.Micro - Binding a button in a sidebar to a method in a ViewModel

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have a problem with binding a button located in a sidebar in my windows phone app. It seems like the buttons binding just dissapears..

Here's my code at the moment

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

        <sidebar:SidebarControl x:Name="sidebarControl"
                            HeaderText="WP"
                            HeaderBackground="YellowGreen"
                            HeaderForeground="White"
                            SidebarBackground="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">

            <sidebar:SidebarControl.SidebarContent>
                <Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="380">


                    <Button Content="Go to page 2"  x:Name="GoToPage2"/>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                </Grid>


            </sidebar:SidebarControl.SidebarContent>

            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              Margin="12">
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}">Your current view goes here</TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </sidebar:SidebarControl>



    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

At the moment I am using a nuget for the sidebar called SidebarWP8. Maybe Calinbrun.Micro doesnt work with this? Or do I have to insert a binding to the VM in a grid?

Here's the method in the ViewModel:

```
private readonly INavigationService navigationService;

public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
{
  this.navigationService = navigationService;
}

public void GoToPage2()
{
   navigationService.UriFor<Page2ViewModel>().Navigate();
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working there? Your button does not have a click handler assigned, just a Name. You have to add Click="..." or a command.

Comment: According to the documentation at Caliburn.Micro it should work if the x:="exampleName" is the same as the methodname? The button works outside the sidebar scope but when it is inside the scope the binding doesnt work anymore. It doesnt call the method. Anyhow thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<Button cm:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action GoToPage2()]" />`

This should work, because of the other commenter is correct with respect to the default controls... Custom controls require adding some more handling in which can be a pain in the butt but doing it with the short hand above CM will look for that property in the button and process accordingly.

Comment: Given that you're using the default event and action this can be simplified to Message.Attach="GoToPage2".

Answer (score 0):

I checked the source for Caliburn Micro: I handles the convention binding by traversing the visual tree to find elements with a name. But it only checks the default **Content** property for each control.

That means it will only go through the **Content** or **Children** elements and not Custom properties like **SidebarContent**, so named elements will not be found there.

You have to wire it up by hand (by binding a command or adding a **click** handler).

Comment: with CM and MVVM you don't do click handlers...  It's all done within the viewmodel for the associated view.